# c++ stack class template implementation using singly linked list

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to implement stack in c++ using singly linked list, but I am getting some problems. Push is working fine but pop removes the top but is unable to be updated to next. Also print function is getting read access violation exception. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

template <class T>

class node {
public:
  T data;
  node<T>* next;
};  

template <class T>

class Stack {
private:
  node<T>* top;
public:
  Stack() {
    top = nullptr;
}
bool isEmpty() {
    if (top == nullptr)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
T Top() {
    if (top)
        return top->data;
    else
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
}
void push(const T & val) {
    if (top == nullptr) {
        top = new node<T>;
        top->next = nullptr;
        top->data = val;
    }
    else {
        node<T>* temp = new node<T>;
        temp->data = val;
        top->next = temp;
        top = temp;
    }
}
void pop() {
    if (top == nullptr) {
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << top->data << " is popped" << endl;
        node<T>* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
void print() {
    node<T>* temp = top;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
   }
   };
```

main function to test the stack class

```
 int main()
 {
    Stack<int> s;
 bool flag = true;
 while (flag)
 {
     cout << "1. Push   2. Pop    3. Print    4. Quit" << endl;
     int choice;
     cin >> choice;
     switch (choice) {
     case(1):
         cout << "Enter a number to push in Stack?";
         int n;
         cin >> n;
         s.push(n);
         break;
     case(2):
         s.pop();
         break;
     case(3):
         s.print();
         break;
     case(4):
         cout << "Quitting program........." << endl;
         return 1;
     default:
         cout << "Invalid choice!!" << endl;
         break;
     }
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In `push()` you wrote `top->next = temp`. It should be `temp->next = top`.

Comment: thanks a lot, just a 1 small mistake had my head scratching. thanks for pointing it out.